# Referencing to a file inside war

Tags: java, jsp

I have source folder `test`, in what there is package `Resources.Data`, that among others contains files `data[0].xml`, that I want to reference in webpage (it is acceptable that all files in that directory are visible). After I build the war, files are in `war\WEB-INF\classes\Resources\Data`. I can make a manual duplicate, to top level, but it seems a dumb thing to do.

My question is: How do I refence `data[0].xml` or is duplicate 'not a dumb thing to do'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the resource to be visible to the browser, then don't put it under `/WEB-INF`. Files in there are not visible.

It looks like you need to chance your build so that those resources are stored elsewhere, rather than copying them around.

Comment: @Margus: Nope, it's a hard-and-fast rule

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file directly in the war.

```
InputStream in = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/Resources/Data/data[0].xml");
```

You can then do whatever you need with the `InputStream`. This should occur inside of Java code, not in JSP.

You should consider storing this above the WEB-INF folder, though, so that it can be served directly. Duplicating the file is unnecessary.